# modules is direct sum of simple submodule all of which are isomorphic to simple module

Tags: modules

I'm looking for an article or source that deals with modules with this property:

$M$ is $R$-module which is direct sum of simple submodules all of which are isomorphic to simple module.
I want to know more about this module and their properties.

Comment: Such a module is called semisimple.

Comment: I know this module is semisimple but I want to use this fact:all simple submodue is isomorphic.

Comment: A bit of context would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in basic Wedderburn theory, given an $R$ module $M$, you call the sum of all simple submodules of $M$ which are isomorphic to a simple $R$ module $S$ a "homogeneous component of $M$".

For semisimple (Artinian) rings, the homogeneous components of the ring itself are exactly the simple rings in the Wedderburn decomposition.

I suppose one property you could draw from this is that their endomorphism rings are [full linear rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_linear_ring#Full_linear_rings) over a division ring. (The division ring being the division ring of endomorphisms of $S$, which is common to all of the modules.)

And as others have noted they are obviously semisimple. What is nicer than semisimple? (Besides simple? and f.g. semisimple?)